# IOS App compatible with previous versions

Tags: ios6, storyboard, automatic-ref-counting

I want to develop a app in IOS6 and it should work on iphone 4s, 5 , iPad and iPad mini. Will the app work if the devices have previous versions of IOS. 
Also can I use storyboard and ARC features in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

ARC needs iOS4 at least. Storyboards require iOS5, Autolayout requires iOS6. You won't be able to use any of the iOS6 specific API calls if the app is installed on devices with a lesser OS.

Set the Project's deployment target to the minimum iOS version you want to support.

Comment: So I will have to specify view layouts separately for the devices supported ?

Comment: Yes. There is plenty of documentation on how to write controllers for Universal (those that work on iPhone and iPad) apps.

Comment: Wat about the UI elements in each view, how can we specify it to reposition or resize based on screen size? Should we use separate XIB's in each case.

Comment: None of this has to do with different devices. It's all about the version of iOS on each device.